# Change color of one letter in label. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, tkinter, label

I can change color of all text in label, but I want to change color of one letter.

Is that possible?

I use `tkiner` and python 3.3.

Comment: Use second label with one letter. You can put both labels in one frame or make own widget.

Comment: @furas is right. You can not do this in one label. You can use a text widget and make in uneditable.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to change the color of one letter in a label. However, you can use a text widget instead of a label to color just a single character. You could also use a canvas widget.